# How can I upgrade rustc hostool version from 1.59 to 1.60 (or higher) on Yocto Kirkstone?

Tags: embedded-linux, yocto, rust-cargo

I am working on a Yocto project since a few months. We are working with a Kirkstone version but I need now to integrate a module which absolutely need to be cross-compiled with a rust version minimum of 1.60. The thing is that on the poky, rustc is given with the 1.59 version, even on the last revision of the Kirkstone branch... How can I upgrade it without having to migrate on Mickledore ?

Thank you for your advice guys !

I tried to migrate on Mickledore but seems not to be the best solution because I have to modify a lot of layers (and even when it is compatible, I have to change layer.conf of each which is not very scalable).

Comment: Have you checked the [meta-rust](https://github.com/meta-rust/meta-rust/) layer? For older yocto releases I think it could be a way forward.

Comment: Indeed, I managed to correct my problem by recovering the meta-rust (on the master branch) which is in version 1.66.1. It's not very pretty at the moment, but it works. I still don't understand why this update isn't integrated into Kirkstone's poky if it's compatible... 
Thanks for the tip!